# Not bathing a female hamster for 2 months

Tags: health, hamsters

My hamster just gave birth 3 weeks ago, and today it gives birth again. I heard that they can't bath using bathing sand for 28 days since.

My concern is, I've read through some articles and their conclusion was that if hamsters get smelly, they will get infection.

Is this true?

Comment: Have you considered the health issues of having a second litter 3 weeks after the previous litter?

Comment: Please keep your male and female hamsters apart from now on, it isn't good on her body for her to have back to back litters like this, and she will struggle to produce enough milk for each consecutive litter.

Answer (score 2):

My sister's hamster has never been given a sand bath, as we didn't realise that it was a thing and it lived for 3 years. So I don't think that 2 months will be the end of the world.

But if you think they are developing problems, then I'd go to the veterinarian.